# Lambda that uses dynamic cast

Tags: c++, templates, vector, lambda

Let's suppose that we have 3 classes:

```
class A
{
public:
    int a;
    virtual ~A() = default;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    int b;
};

class C : public A
{
public:
    int c;
};
```

And a vector that contains polymorphic objects derived from A

```
std::vector<A*> objects;
```

I want to have a template method, that will return me an object from vector of type gived in template, if that object exists, but I don't know how to write it..
This not work:

```
template<typename ComponentType>
ComponentType * GetComponent()
{
    bool pred = std::find_if(objects.begin(), objects.end(),
    [=](A * obj)
    {
        return 
            dynamic_cast<ComponentType*>(obj) != nullptr;
    });

    return pred != objects.end();
}
```

I know that it could be done with that code:

```
template<typename ComponentType>
ComponentType * GetComponent()
{
    for (item : objects)
    {
        auto casted = dynamic_cast<ComponentType*>(item);

        if (casted)
            return casted;
    }

    return nullptr;
}
```

But I want to use lambda.

Comment: `bool pred`? You want `std::find_if` to return an iterator, not to immediately cast it to a bool.

Comment: Your terminology is a little off, as is your knowledge of [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find). First of all `pred` is an abbreviation of *predicate*. And `std::find_if` doesn't return a predicate, *or* a boolean value. It returns an *iterator*. Then there's the issue of you attempting to compare a `bool` with an iterator, and return a bool result from your function.

Comment: And `return pred != objects.end();`, but the return type is `ComponentType *`.

Comment: crap, maybe because I tried many ways to do it,  in the end I was not seeing bad lambda type... thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not work at least because [std::find_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) returns an *iterator*, not a *bool*.

You might change your solution to fix it and return either a pointer to the element or *nullptr* if there is no such element:

```
template<typename ComponentType>
ComponentType * GetComponent()
{
    auto it = std::find_if(objects.begin(), objects.end(),
    [](A * obj)
    {
        return dynamic_cast<ComponentType*>(obj) != nullptr;
    });

    return it != objects.end()
        ? dynamic_cast<ComponentType*>(*it)
        : nullptr;
}
```

---

Note, that it is better to avoid *dynamic_cast* at all if it is possible. For example, you might add a virtual method to `A` class which identifies an object somehow, then override it in `B` and `C` and use to find a requested object.

Comment: Yes I was thinking about adding for example string type, and overriding it in derived class, and I think that will be the best way for recognizing types, but I wanted to see how to use lambda in this way.